# jQuery .css() not working in IE 6,7,8 and Firefox, but works in Chrome, Safari, Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery

UPDATE: THIS HAS BEEN SOLVED.

I'm trying to change the default style of an Assistly site through JavaScript, because the stylesheet is not editable by me. It's working fine in Chrome, Safari, Opera, and IE9; but not in IE 6,7,8 or any Firefox.

In the code below the first two lines that are setting an h2 and an image are working across all browsers, but the .css() lines are not. Why would .css() not work in certain browsers?

Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$("#support-header .wrapper h2").first().html('<h2>Real Estate Help</h2>');
$("#company-header .wrapper").html('<a href="http://help.mysite.com/"><img src="http://www.mysite.com/logo-red.png" /></a>');
$("body").css({'background': '#FFFFFF !important'});
$("#company-header").css({'background': 'none !important'});
$("#support-header").css({'background': 'none !important', 'border-bottom': 'none', 'padding': '0'});
$("#company-support-portal").css({'background-image': 'url(http://www.mysite.com/container-bg2.jpg) !important', 'background-repeat': 'repeat-x', 'margin-top': '10px'});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Should those spaces be there, in the file name? And what about all these `importants`?

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please.

Comment: Link added. Spaces removed - somehow those were inserted when copying in code here. I put the !importants in to override other CSS already set in a stylesheet that I cannot change.

Comment: It might be as simple as what GolezTrol is getting at: spaces are invalid in URLs, and !important statements are going to absolutely kill your inheritence. If the various browsers have a different way of resolving stacked "!important" statements, it might be the CSS and not the JS at all.

Comment: There are no spaces in the actual code. It happened when copying into Stack Overflow. Removing the !important statements makes the code stop working in ALL browsers. It's needed because the CSS which, I cannot edit, already has !important statements specified in it.

Answer (score 4):

I will add to what others have said: I suspect the problem may be related to the `!important` flag.

The question is why do you need it? You're setting this on an inline style, so that ought to override any other styles anyway; the only thing that won't be overridden by default on an inline style is another style that is marked `!important`, so I assume that's what you're trying to do.

The trouble is that as soon as you use `!important`, you're basically telling the browser that this style should trump everything else; inheritance and precedence go out of the window.

If you have multiple `!important` styles on the same element, both will have equal precedence, so you can never really be sure what's going to happen. Some browsers will pick up one, some the other.

The real lesson to be taken from this is to avoid using `!important` in your stylesheets, unless it is absolutely unavoidable, and certainly avoid it for anything that you will subsequently want to override.

Due to the way CSS arranges things in order of precedence and inheritance, there are in fact very very few cases where `!important` is actually needed. There is almost always an alternative (better) way of doing it.

So the short answer: Re-work your stylesheets to get rid of the `!important` markers. Your jQuery code is not going to work correctly until you do this (and in fact, looking at the number of `!important` markers in your site, your CSS on its own might already be struggling to get things right as it is)

Comment: Spudley as I've said in other comments. I cannot remove the !important in the stylesheet! It's not owned by me, it's owned by Assistly.

So the question is.... **how do I remove the styles in the stylesheet that is uneditable by me?**

I've come across this site, but I haven't been able to get it to work. http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript

Any ideas on how to remove the CSS that is in a stylesheet that is not editable by me and add my own styles through Javascript?

Comment: @kfawcett - the way `!important` is being used in the stylesheets is poor quality code, so that reflects badly on Assistly. If at all possible, I would suggest trying to find a way to replace that stylesheet, because it is the root of all your problems. With that many `!important`s, it will seriously impede your ability to adjust the look and feel of your site at all. Hacking around it may help, but it won't solve the problem in the long term. If you are able to add Javascript code, then hopefully you can change the page template? Simply change the CSS URL, and load your own styles instead.

Comment: After actually looking at the code the styles are internal, not in an external style sheet. How can I change those through JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: @kfawcett - ouch. That'll to be tough to work with. You can change the class of the element in question and thus your own styles, but there is the potential for changes like that to break JS/jQuery code that looks for the class. It is possible to delete rules from a stylesheet using Javascript, but it's really fiddly (and IE breaks the standards so you have to do browser-specific code). You access your CSS as an object, but finding the ones you need to delete is painful. See http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/621/addingandremovingrules.html for an example.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `!important` from the your code. `!important` should only be used within stylesheets, not within inline attributes.

Comment: Removing them makes the javascript not work in any of the browsers.

Comment: @kfawcett - that is because you've seriously overused `!important` in your stylesheets as well. `!important` should be considered a tool of last resort.

Answer (score 0):

In IE, it works well to use

```
element.css('property', 'value')
```

Although  you then need a separate line for every property.

Note: you can specify important easily with

```
$.('#elid').css('display', 'block !important')
```